# Creating a request button to save the word in the database which is typed in search box along with the logged in user name in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have a program in codeigniter where in, after logging in there will be a search box to search(ajax search) the data from database,it will be in the form of link.
But if i have any word which is not in the database, it should display "No data found" and there should be a "Request button".
On clicking the request button, the typed word in the search box should save in the database along with the logged in user name, and it should display request sent on screen.

This is my controller for ajaxsearch:

```
  if(is_null($this->input->get('id')))
    {
    $this->load->view('data');    
    }
    else
    {
    $this->load->model('Info_model'); 

    $data['Infotable']=$this->Info_model->Infotable($this->input->get('id')); 

    $this->load->view('view_result',$data);
    }
```

This is my view:

1.Data page

```
<form action="" method="get">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" >SEARCH</span>
        <input autocomplete="off" id="search"  type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search " >
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>   
 <div class="space"></div>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>Test/ajaxsearch" method="post">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" >SEARCH</span>
        <input autocomplete="off" id="search" name="search" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search " >
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>   
 <div class="space"></div>
</form>
```

then in your ajaxsearch()

```
public function ajaxsearch() {
        if(@$this->input->post('search') != "") {

            $data['Infotable']=$this->Info_model->Infotable($this->input->post('search'));
            if(count($data['Infotable']) > 0) {
                $this->load->view('view_result',$data); 
            }else {
                $data['dataNotFound'] = "No data Found";
                $this->load->view('view_result',$data);
            } 
        }
    }
```

then in view_result

```
 <?php
    if(isset($dataNotFound)) {
        echo $dataNotFound;
    }else {
        foreach($Infotable as $objects) {
            echo $objects;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: give your form a 

id="formID"

$("#search").keyup(function(e) {
   var search = $('#search').val();
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code==13 && search.trim().length != 0) {
        $('#formID').submit();
    }
});

Comment: Yea it is working. I want to add a search button when new name is typed.

Comment: if(count($data['Infotable']) > 0)
     $this->load->view('view_result',$data);
else
    //do your think no data found

Comment: <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#search").keyup(function(){
   var str=  $("#search").val();
    if(str == "") {
      $( "#txtHint" ).html("<b>Information will be listed here...</b>"); 
       }else {
          $.get( "<?php echo base_url();?>user/ajaxsearch?id="+str, function( data ){
             $( "#txtHint" ).html( data ); });
    }
 });  
 });  
</script>
 This is my javascript code

Comment: This is another view page i.e., view_result: if(!empty($Infotable ))  
  { 
  $outputdata = ''; 
    foreach($Infotable as $objects)    
  {   
        $outputdata .= '<tr> 
                   <td >'.$objects->id.'</td>
          <td><a href="'.$objects->url.'">'.$objects->name.'</a></td> 
         </tr> ';
     }  

        echo $outputdata; 
     }  
     else  
     {  
    echo 'Data Not Found';    
     }